Geometry Nodes: How to delete a source mesh in a stack with same modifiers?
In the screenhot below you see a way to distribute objects on the very same source mesh, even if you stack the GN modifiers to do this. All instances use always the same source mesh and aren't distributed on the modifier mesh result before.
Question: Is there a way to hide the source mesh, but the distributed instances stay visible?
If you see the following example:
Let's say we want delete/hide the source plane optionally in one of the modifiers by using a checkbox f.e.
Thank you!
The original post for the screenshot can be found here:
Geometry nodes: Is it possible to "ignore" the modifier stack and use always the source mesh?


In this case, I would keep the source mesh as an independent object and integrate it into your modifier stack with "Object Info".

My current solution is already working with a "controller mesh" that uses a target mesh as the source for distributing instances. I was hoping to avoid using a seperate controller object.

Well, this time I really don't want to claim that this is a good solution (if it could be a possible solution at all), but at least the base mesh is successfully hidden or not displayed:

The problem, as described in the other answer, is that everything that ends up at the output is also visible (in some form).
Conversely, of course, this also means that everything that is visible must be present (in some form).
So since the base mesh must be present but should not be visible, I simply "hide" it by moving all points to world $0$ (deflate) and restoring them with the previously saved original positions of the points on the next pass (inflate).
Simple, effective, ...but not really recommended, because depending on the mesh, computing power is of course lost, and: the elements are still there, even if you can't see them.
(Blender 4.1.1+)

Later I also realized that this actually doesn't work. Without a base model, nothing further can be done. In this sense, you're right. Your solution hides the emitter mesh, but it's not really gone... Nice idea, but ultimately not a solution. It would be good if one could access the base mesh modifier comprehensively. Many thanks nonetheless!
